# Restful API for Amazon Textract - example

Tags: amazon-textract

I'm looking for an example of a RESTFUL API request for Amazon Textract service.

I've been able to find the endpoint: https://textract.us-west-2.amazonaws.com, but no help on Headers and not much on how the Body should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Reference.html).

Anyway, the best way is using the `aws cli`, like:

```
aws textract analyze-document \
 --document '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"bucket","Name":"document"}}' \
 --feature-types '["TABLES","FORMS"]'
```

or one of the AWS SDKs, based on the language you are using

Comment: Is there a .NET version of the SDK?  I've only found java and python - and my app is in c#

Comment: @reginashGina yes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

And it supports Textract: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Textract/

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Wish it wasn't limited to only those in their preview program.